# How do you include resources files in Maven site source cross reference?

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3

Especially of interest are the configuration xml files that are so common.

I'd hope there was a configuration to the JXR plugin.  I tried **/*.xml but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Maven JXR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jxr-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) does provide a way to include/exclude files though not sure if it is just .java files.

You should try `**/*.xml` rather than `*/*.xml`

```
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.xml</include>
      </includes>
```